# Will it be possible to use Java 8 on Glassfish 4.1?

Tags: java, console.log, glassfish-4.1

We currently use Glassfish 4.1 and I really want to use Java 8. Will Glassfish 4.1 work with Java 8 or will I have to upgrade my application container?

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer,

> **Yes.**

GlassFish 4.1 will work with Java 1.8.

Comment: but can't display the console on glassfish 4 with java 8 144 and use eclipse

Comment: Eclipse won't give a console output like NetBeans. Check the logs in the web container. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18158035/2408342).

Comment: It's actually not quite that simple. You also need a minimum update level for Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

In general: updating the jvm version alone rarely leads to issues.

Keep in mind that a lot of work goes into making sure that new Java versions are backwards compatible. And most importantly: a new jvm can always run byte code compiled for an older version of Java. The other way round (upgrading your application server for example) is much more likely to cause significant problems.

So, the (unspecific) answer here is: just try it. And for the record: Java 9 (or newer) with the new module system is a completely different story. But at least for now, the corresponding checking can be disabled on the command line.

Of course, there can be subtle issues for large applications. A new jvm may use different defaults for say, garbage collection settings (or use a different gc in the first place). That can of course change the runtime characteristics of large applications running in a large stack.

Comment: The question was explicitly about Java 8. But I added a bit to make that more clear.

Comment: Why would you _"just try it"_ when you can get the definitive answer from the documentation? Apart from potentially wasting time, the danger is that you try some version/update of Java that appears to work fine, but it is actually unsupported, and may later result in unexpected problems in Glassfish.

Comment: If one doesn't have the means to test environmental changes before turning them into production, one has problems anyway. The point is: the risk of this not working is containable. Sure, your answer is the most correct stance. But surprise, you found that it should work. Does that mean the OP will not run into issues. Not necessarily. What if he has something else in his stack he forgot about? Again, he is back to trying.

Answer (score 1):

The best (and easiest) approach for determining whether Java version 'x' will work Glassfish version 'y' is to refer to the Release Note for that specific Glassfish release.

The Release Note will have a section titled **Hardware and Software Requirements**, and within that a sub-section titled **Required JDK Versions**.

[For Release 4.1 the answer is](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/4.0/release-notes.pdf):

> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition Release 4.1 requires **Oracle JDK 7
>   Update 65 or later, or Oracle JDK 8 Update 20 or later**.

Notes:

- The word "*later*" in the part stating "*Oracle JDK 8 Update 20 or later*" is ambiguous, but it is referring only to the update level for the specified JDK version. Do not interpret "*later*" as implying that Glassfish 4.1 might work with Java 9 or higher. It would be much clearer if the wording was:

  > GlassFish Server Open Source Edition Release 4.1 requires Oracle JDK 7
  >   **using** Update 65 or later, or Oracle JDK 8 **using** Update 20 or later.
- It is incorrect to state that "*Glassfish 4.1 will work with Java 7 or Java 8*", because in both cases a minimum update level is also required.
- You can also get the minimum JDK requirements from Glassfish itself. Under the root of the unzipped download in a file named **README.TXT** there is a section titled **0. Prerequisite**. For Glassfish 4.1 it is worth noting that the information given conflicts with that in the Release Note!...

  > GlassFish 4.1 requires Oracle JDK 7 Update 65+ or Oracle JDK 8 Update
  >   5+.

  In the odd cases where the requirements in the documentation conflict I'd always be inclined to choose the higher update level, and most of the time this is unlikely to be an issue.